# difference in GMSGeocoder address results and Google Places API autocomplete results

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete

I have a question.. regarding the Google Maps API, in my app I am using Autocomplete to search for the address which is using Google Places Autocomplete SDK to search for the address, on the other hand I am also showing the map on which, on move of the marker it shows address , but when I tap an address on the autocomplete search I didn't get the exact address on the map ( for the map I am using reverse geocoding to get the address) , is it true that both the results will differ??

Answer (score 0):

The Geocoder is intended for locating postal addresses.  The Places API is intended for locating "places".  They have different databases, so the results can and do differ.

Comment: so what should be the correct implementation in this scenario? if I want to implement search as well as provide address on map ?

Comment: Your question was "is it true that both the results will differ", the answer is yes.  Sounds like you have a different question.

Comment: well a quick suggestion I need.. sorry to mention this second question with the first one... after that the thread will be closed..